# VerifyError in Gson classes

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

I rebase a class with the following code:

```
DynamicType.Unloaded unloaded = new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED).rebase(typeDescription,
                ClassFileLocator.Simple.of(className, classBytes,
                        ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of((ClassLoader) classLoader))).method(
                ElementMatchers.isPackagePrivate().and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isAbstract()))).intercept(
                MethodDelegation.to(PackagePrivateInterceptor.class)).transform(
                MethodTransformer.Simple.withModifiers(Visibility.PUBLIC)).make();
        return new ClassPair(unloaded.load((ClassLoader) classLoader,
                ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION.withProtectionDomain(
                        classLoader.getClass().getProtectionDomain())).getLoaded(), unloaded.getBytes());
```

When loading the class `class com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor`

it goes through the constructor until finally it gets to the class initializer of `com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap`.

During that initialization, I get a VerifyError:

```
1:24:20.227 [main] ERROR   [io.hakansson.dynamicjar.core.main.Bootstrap] - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.VerifyError: Illegal type at constant pool entry 195 in class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$1
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap$1.thenComparing$accessor$vT023QbO(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/util/Comparator; @2: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 195 is invalid
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b700 c3b0                         

    at io.hakansson.dynamicjar.core.api.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:52)
    at io.hakansson.dynamicjar.core.main.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:42)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Illegal type at constant pool entry 195 in class com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap$1
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap$1.thenComparing$accessor$vT023QbO(Ljava/util/function/Function;)Ljava/util/Comparator; @2: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Constant pool index 195 is invalid
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2a2b b700 c3b0                         

    at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.classInitializer$oNOjADym(LinkedTreeMap.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap.(LinkedTreeMap.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$13.construct$original$gt92dwVY(ConstructorConstructor.java:207)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$13.construct$original$gt92dwVY$accessor$lof1omy8(ConstructorConstructor.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$13$auxiliary$oB71rVyd.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.hakansson.dynamicjar.nestedjarclassloader.PackagePrivateInterceptor.intercept(PackagePrivateInterceptor.java:29)
    at com.google.gson.internal.ConstructorConstructor$13.construct(ConstructorConstructor.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:167)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read$original$ZTjOtCtb(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read$original$ZTjOtCtb$accessor$WgRdwpwl(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1$auxiliary$41HBhnNS.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.hakansson.dynamicjar.nestedjarclassloader.PackagePrivateInterceptor.intercept(PackagePrivateInterceptor.java:29)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read$original$bOjIYDn5(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read$original$bOjIYDn5$accessor$hMWEZRZS(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper$auxiliary$U1tyihKy.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.hakansson.dynamicjar.nestedjarclassloader.PackagePrivateInterceptor.intercept(PackagePrivateInterceptor.java:29)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read$original$ZTjOtCtb(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read$original$ZTjOtCtb$accessor$WgRdwpwl(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1$auxiliary$41HBhnNS.call(Unknown Source)
    at io.hakansson.dynamicjar.nestedjarclassloader.PackagePrivateInterceptor.intercept(PackagePrivateInterceptor.java:29)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:216)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:879)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:817)
```

For reference, the interceptor basically just manually checks for package-private access (since package private methods were made public) and then just calls `superCall.call()`. I don't believe the issue lies there.

Any ideas?

EDIT:
Here's the `PackagePrivateInterceptor`:
    public class PackagePrivateInterceptor {

```
@RuntimeType
@BindingPriority(1)
public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> superCall, @Origin Class targetClass, @Origin String method) throws
        Exception
{

    Class callingClass = new InternalSecurityManager().getCallingClass();
    String targetPackage = targetClass.getPackage().getName();
    if (!callingClass.getPackage().getName().equals(targetPackage)) {
        throw new IllegalAccessError(callingClass + " cannot access method " + method + " of Class " + targetClass);
    }

    //Default:
    return superCall.call();
}

private static class InternalSecurityManager extends SecurityManager {
    Class getCallingClass() {
        Class[] classContext = getClassContext();
        for (Class current : classContext) {
            if (current.getName().startsWith("java.") ||
                    current.getName().equals(PackagePrivateInterceptor.class.getName()) ||
                    current.getName().equals(InternalSecurityManager.class.getName()))
            {
                continue;
            }
            return current;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to find calling Class");
    }
}
```

EDIT2:
The following code does not trigger the issue:

```
//Only package-private methods should be proxied.
            DynamicType.Unloaded unloaded = new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED).rebase(typeDescription,
                    ClassFileLocator.Simple.of(className, classBytes,
                            ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of((ClassLoader) classLoader))).method(
                    ElementMatchers.isPackagePrivate().and(ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isAbstract()))).intercept(
                    MethodDelegation.to(PackagePrivateInterceptor.class)).transform(
                    MethodTransformer.Simple.withModifiers(Visibility.PUBLIC)).make();
            DynamicType.Loaded loaded = unloaded.load((ClassLoader) classLoader,
                    ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION.withProtectionDomain(
                            classLoader.getClass().getProtectionDomain()));
            if (className.equals("com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap"))
                System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(loaded.getBytes()));
            return new ClassPair(loaded.getLoaded(), unloaded.getBytes());
```

But the following does:

```
//All non-private methods should be proxied
            //TODO: Actually, the class itself should be made visible and still only package-private methods should be proxied.
            DynamicType.Unloaded unloaded = new ByteBuddy().with(TypeValidation.DISABLED).rebase(typeDescription,
                    ClassFileLocator.Simple.of(className, classBytes,
                            ClassFileLocator.ForClassLoader.of((ClassLoader) classLoader))).method(
                    ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isPrivate()).and(
                            ElementMatchers.not(ElementMatchers.isAbstract()))).intercept(
                    MethodDelegation.to(PackagePrivateInterceptor.class)).transform(
                    MethodTransformer.Simple.withModifiers(Visibility.PUBLIC)).make();
            return new ClassPair(unloaded.load((ClassLoader) classLoader,
                    ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.INJECTION.withProtectionDomain(
                            classLoader.getClass().getProtectionDomain())).getLoaded(), unloaded.getBytes());
```

Comment: Could you produce a recreation of this error? Normally, this should not happen and I am not capable of creating this error. Byte Buddy uses ASM under the covers which takes care of the entire constant pool so I assume that there is a problem in the library.

Comment: The method code is `aload_0 aload_1 invokespecial [195] areturn` which looks reasonable, i.e. not trashed. So the question is, what happened to the constant pool which ought to contain a method descriptor at index `195`. Maybe posting the result of `unloaded.getBytes()` (as hex dump) could help…

Comment: @RafaelWinterHalter, I've tried to make a clean recreation but the problem does not arise. Obviously it's something that I do, but the thing is I don't do any manipulation of the bytes or anything.
I'll investigate and try to see what exactly it is I do that triggers this error.

Comment: @Holger,
Here is the hexdump of `com/google/gson/internal/LinkedTreeMap`:
http://pastebin.com/76wg3SwK

I have no knowledge of bytecode what so ever, so any help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you write any custom components? It looks to me like you register some form of custom transformer or Java agent that trashes your class file.

Comment: I do have one transformer, but it's ByteBuddy native.
On every package-private, non-abstract method:
`intercept(
                    MethodDelegation.to(PackagePrivateInterceptor.class)).transform(
                    MethodTransformer.Simple.withModifiers(Visibility.PUBLIC))`

Comment: What version of Byte Buddy are you using? As @Holger said, the byte code looks just fine so there seems to be something wrong with the constant pool index. That pool is handled by ASM directly. What does your working reproduction do differently than your actual project?

Comment: The hex dump contains the wrong class, `LinkedTreeMap`. The error is regarding `LinkedTreeMap$1`, an anonymous inner class of `LinkedTreeMap`.

Comment: @erikh: You can ask Byte Buddy to dump all classes by setting `-Dnet.bytebuddy.dump=/some/location` property on application start up.

Comment: @Harold
I followed Rafels instructions to dump to file, and I've shared them on Drive. There's apparently a lot of Auxilliary types generated and I didn't know if you needed them so they're included.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_HSPb2WlLelRmZqb2xKNGNMMzg

I'm pretty sure I'm at fault here, but if you see anything, I'd be most grateful!

Comment: I updated the issue with two new examples, one which generates the issue, and one which does not. As far as I can tell, the only difference is selectors on methods. But I guess I do something else that I cannot see.

Comment: Okay, so I've managed to reproduce the error in a clean test.
I've pushed it to GH here:
https://github.com/erikhakansson/bytebuddytest
Run mvn clean install and either run the resulting jar-with-dependencies or run the Main class with Intellij or whatever and it will [not] work. You must run mvn clean install first, though to copy .class files from dependencies.

Comment: I just realised something. I'm not by a computer now, so I can't verify it, but if I transform a method that's already public, or one that is private, with the public modifier, could that cause this issue? Or is bytebuddy intelligent enough to handle that? I'm thinking that maybe I'm creating "public public" and "public private" methods, which obviously make no sense.

Comment: Ok, this is weird. Like I said in the previous comment, I tried to filter out public methods using elementmatchers. Success! Suddenly I don't have the issue anymore. So I figured it was my transformer to change visibility. However, I still want to intercept public methods, so I added another intercept for public methods, but without the transformer. But then the issue came back. So, basically, I get the issue when I intercept public methods in this class, even without a transformer.

Comment: @eirkh Thank you for the reproduction. I will try to figure this out. Byte Buddy is smart enough to define correct modifiers. That it does not happen for non-public methods means that the error is probably made when you hit one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed a bug in Byte Buddy. The problem is that you are rebasing a Java 6 class on a Java 8 VM where the `Comparable` interface is implementing several default methods. You instruct Byte Buddy to override these methods and you also instruct the library to invoke these default methods from an overridden implementation. This is not legal for Java 6 class files even if the VM is running Java 8.

If I cange your matcher to:

```
not(isPrivate().or(isAbstract()).or(isDefaultMethod()))
```

the error goes away. I will fix this in a future version of Byte Buddy.

This error is currently not catched by either Byte Buddy or ASM which yields the strange error message.

**Update**: The error is now resolved in version 1.4.13.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. So I suppose it was an error by me, triggering a bug in ASM/ByteBuddy.

It works when adding isDefaultMethod.

However, I can't update to the latest version of ByteBuddy as that triggers a new issue, but I'll post another question about that.

Comment: Regarding the other issue, never mind that, it was apparently solved in 1.4.13. It was something about not finding generic type "E".